# Get the exact point in which a Polygon Intersects with a polyline

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask you something regarding Intersection on SQL Server. 
I am running a project in which I am using a gmap. I have a polygon through which some polylines are passing through and some are not. I am using the STIntersection in order to get the exactly part of polyline which is in the polygon. 
Below is the t-sql that I am using to achieve this.

The issue now is that I want to find the exactly point in which each polyline touches the polygon through passing out. Do you have any workaround concerning this?

```
DECLARE @polygon geography;

DECLARE @polyline geography;

SET @g = (select Polygon from Polygons where id = @polygonID)

SET @h = (select GeogPolyline from Polylines where ID = @polylineId)
SET     @intersectedpart = (SELECT @g.STIntersection(@h).STAsText() )
```

Comment: A polyline can intersect a polygon at more than one point.  Do you have criteria for determining which is the best intersection point or is any arbitrary intersection point okay?

Comment: Thanks tgolisch for your question.  I would like to catch only the points when polylines enter in the polygon. Not the points when polyline is getting out of polygon.

Comment: If you have an *answer* to your question (which it looks like you do, by your edit), please post it *as* an answer. That way you can mark it as accepted (after an enforced delay, IIRC) and then we know that you no longer need help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to resolve this using the below :

```
SET @result = (SELECT @g.STIntersection(@h).STStartPoint())
```

Using this you are geting the first point of intersection between the polyline and polygon